# How to set what answers are true in CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have a program test. Some questions may have a couple of answers, and some only one answers. When only one answer, I use this structure for every question: `Dictionary<RadioButton, bool> answers`.(`bool` saves whether answer is true or false) How to do the same, but with `CheckedListBox`.

Separate class for questions:

```
class Question
    {
        public Question(Label lab, Image img, Dictionary<RadioButton, bool> ans_rb, Dictionary<CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection, bool> ans_chb)
        {
            text = lab;
            answers_rb = ans_rb;
            isAnswered = false;
        }
        public Label text { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<RadioButton, bool> answers_rb { get; set; }// = new Dictionary<RadioButton, bool>();
        public bool isAnswered;

    }
```

Comment: Im not sure why they're linked to the buttons at all, just have a separate class for question, wrong answers and correct answer(s) and then update radio button text with the possible answers etc.

Comment: I have such class(see edited post). But how to add to it CheckedListBox and mark what answers are true?

Comment: your edit shows a class using buttons.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: I just need to rewrite Dictionary<RadioButton, bool> to Dictionary<string, bool>, and then update text of controls?

Comment: pretty much yeah, or a list of answers with an int for the index of the correct one